# Безопасно ли использовать selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, автоматизация

не оставляет ли он каких то следов по которым можно определить что производилась автоматизация? собираюсь использовать вместе с python

Comment: спасибо за быстрые ответы, именно это я хотел узнать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно звучащий вопрос.

А какие следы он должен оставлять? Если ты имеешь ввиду "увидят ли сайты по которым я лазил через селениум что я так делал" -- то нет. Не увидят. Для сайтов ты простой пользователь (ну, правда, если не делать действий черезчур быстро :) )

Если же ты имел ввиду что-то другое, то настоятельно советую перефразировать вопрос так, что бы на него можно было дать обьективно верный ответ.

Comment: Я бы сказал доплнить

Answer (score 2):

Безопасность - это вещь относительно рисков. Если риск сломать код, то да тогда эта штука опасна. Делайте бекапы перед тестированием.
С точки зрения безопасности браузера, относительно безопасное приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Webdriver всего лишь позволяет взаимодействовать с браузером через его драйвер, где действия, которые выполняет пользователь, выполняются при помощи написанного вами кода. Никакого вмешательства помимо он не осуществляет.